# Как лучше и правильнее реализовать новости

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache

Есть блок с превьюшками новости (изображение,заголовок,дата;)
При нажатии на блок происходит переход на страницу новости,где выводиться вся новость.
Принцип работы сейчас такой: при нажатии передается параметр (id) и происходит переход на news.php ,где формируется запрос на основе этого параметра и выводиться вся информация.
Правильно ли так?Как реализовать лучше?
Сейчас url выглядит косо news.php/?id=1 
даже если по title делать все равно по мне так косо.
Подскажите,пожалуйста.
Спасибо!

Comment: Для новости можно в редакторе создать поле краткого заголовка и делать красивый и информативный url по типу http://lenta.ru/news/2015/08/04/minion/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все так и делают, просто используют **ЧПУ**. Для **apache** реализуется с помощью **mod_rewrite**. Потому ссылки выглядят красивее, например **/news/1** или **/news/save-the-cat**.

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант создать поле identy в которое писать дату новости (пример identy = '**2015/08/04**').

А url-ы генерировать из двух значений identy и id (пример '**site.loc/2015/08/04/1**'). Как сказал человек передо мной разрулить передачу параметров с помощью **mod_rewrite**.

Гибкость такого подхода в возможности открыть страницу со всеми новостями за определенный день.